# Exception thrown: Culture is not supported

Tags: sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2019, culture

I have a strange issue.
2 computers running the same WinForms project connected to the same SQL server database.
Both running w11/x64 with the same regional settings on both machines. And VS2019 on both.

When debugging the project on one of the computers an exception is thrown:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> 
System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: culture
3072 (0x0c00) is an invalid culture identifier.
```

When googling the issue, there seems to be people that have fixed it with some SQL server fix, but that can't be the issue here since it works on one computer but not the other.

Any suggestions on where to go from here?

Comment: This could be SQL Server side, if you are somehow parameterising the culture used in the SQL, such as in `TRY_PARSE`; with no code, and no idea what culture is expected here, though, I can only suggest you ensure that the needed culture(s) are install on *both* the SQL Server host and the client machines.

Comment: @Larnu can it really be a sql server side problem? since the identical w11 settings on 2 different computers with the same identical code running on both works on one but not the other.

Comment: It's possible, yes (especially if you're using CLR objects). As I said, if you are *parametrising* the culture, the error could appear on the SQL Server side. But, again, with no code I can't add more than that.

Comment: @Larnu it adds the TimeZoneId to the datasets extendedproperties. I'm not really an expert on this stuff:

dataSet.ExtendedProperties[TimeZoneId] = TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id;

TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id value is "FLE Standard Time"

Comment: Errors occur when multiple machines connect to sqlserver. Please refer to the following methods: 1. Check the password of the SA account. 2. Is the connection mode of the machine adopting mixed mode?

Comment: @Lynn-MSFT well the password has to be correct since it connects just fine to the sql server. It is only when using a date and setting the TimeZoneId on the dataset it throws an exception.

Where can I check if the connection mode is mixed?

Comment: @Supernalle I'm sorry for the late reply. Mixed Mode: Instead of using a single WINDOWS authentication. It needs to know the password of the sa account.

Comment: @Lynn-MSFT okay, but I doubt there's a problem with any authentication to the SQL server since i'm able to fetch data otherwise. From other functions I have no problem fetching data from the sql server.

Comment: @Lynn-MSFT on further investigation it seems this happens when using Entity Framework to load entities. Does not happen with a 'regular query'.